# Stratified cox regression in R using package namespace

Tags: r, cox-regression

I'm doing stratified cox regression in R with the survival package:

```
cox <- coxph(response~strata(x), data=data)
```

This works fine, but when using the sampling package the strata function from the survival package is hidden and cannot be used directly.

However, calling it with the explicit namespace `survival::strata` does not create a stratified analysis:

```
library(survival)

# sample data
mort28day <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
daysurv <- c(4,29,24,29,29,29,29,19,29,29,29,3,9,29,15,29,29,11,29,5,13,20,22,29,16,21,9,29,29,15)
levo <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
acbi30 <- data.frame(mort28day, daysurv, levo)

# create survival object
test.Surv <- Surv(acbi30$daysurv, acbi30$mort28day)

test.surv_fit_1 <- survfit(coxph(test.Surv~strata(levo), data=acbi30))
test.surv_fit_2 <- survfit(coxph(test.Surv~survival::strata(levo), data=acbi30))
```

So,

```
test.surv_fit_1$strata
# levo=0 levo=1 
#    12      3 

test.surv_fit_2$strata
# NULL
```

Why is this the case and how can I access this function when it is hidden by `sampling::strata` (apart from detaching the sampling package ;-)

I'm using R version 2.15.2

Thanks, DeltaKappa

---

Update:

As a workaround to using survival::strata together with the sampling package I did

```
library(survival)
library(sampling, pos="package:base")
```

which loads the sampling package with a low search priority right above the base package. Then I can do

```
coxph(test.Surv~strata(levo), data=acbi30)
```

while calling `sampling::strata` explicitly.

Comment: `coxph` looks for certain functions, including `strata`, in the supplied formula to identify as "special" terms. It calls `terms.formula` (via `terms`) with `special = c("strata", "cluster", "tt")`, and it looks like this fails to identify `survival::strata` as a special term. That missing special term then propagates throughout the rest of the calculations and leaves you with no strata. `terms.formula` uses internal code, and I don't have the nerve (or perhaps the know-how) for source-surfing right now.

Comment: I guessed, it would be something in that direction, since assigning `st <- strata(levo)` and using it in the formula `test.Surv~st` also didn't work... thanks for claryfing @BenBarnes

Answer (score 0):

The proximate reason for failure was correctly described in the comments , but there is an incredibly simple fix that was not offered. As you pointed out the `strata` function is not exposed but the use of the triple-colon operator (`:::`) lets you get around that aspect:

```
test.surv_fit_1 <- survfit(coxph(test.Surv~strata(levo), data=acbi30))
test.surv_fit_2 <- survfit(coxph(test.Surv~survival:::strata(levo), data=acbi30))
test.surv_fit_1
#--------
Call: survfit(formula = coxph(test.Surv ~ strata(levo), data = acbi30))

        n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
levo=0 25     13     24      19      NA
levo=1  5      2     NA      13      NA

test.surv_fit_2
#-------------
Call: survfit(formula = coxph(test.Surv ~ survival:::strata(levo), 
    data = acbi30))

      n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
[1,] 30     15     24      19      NA
```

Whether this was the correct solution in the context of using the `sampling` package, I'm not able to render an opinion, but it would definitely circumvent the masking of the `survival:::strata` function.